# Reset fileupload control from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I have a ASP website page where i have a upload control added

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" 
                        BorderStyle="None" Width="215px" onchange="return checkfile();" style="margin-left: 14px" BackColor="#F0F0F0" />
```

From `javascript` i am validating the file which will be uploaded. If it is of type `.exe`  then I will not allow to upload and give a message. if not i will display the file name in label "`lblFileName`" . But the problem if error(in case file is exe) then i want to reset the upload control(`FileUpload1`) . Now it will show only message but allows form to submit along with the `.exe` file.So how I can reset it?

```
 function checkfile() {

     var filename = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
     var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");


     if (lastIndex >= 0) {
         filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
     }

    var FileExt = filename.split('.').pop();

    if (FileExt == "exe") {  

        document.getElementById('<%=lblFileName.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "you cannot attach exe file";
    return false;

     }
    else {
        document.getElementById('<%=lblFileName.ClientID%>').innerHTML = filename;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/clear-a-file-input/) has some good tricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is the problem `onchange="return checkfile();"`

And your function should look like

```
    function checkfile() {

         var filename = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
         var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");


         if (lastIndex >= 0) {
             filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
         }

        var FileExt = filename.split('.').pop();

        if (FileExt == "exe") {         
            document.getElementById('lblFileName').innerHTML = "you cannot attach exe file";
            document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value='';
            return false;

         }
         else {
            document.getElementById('lblFileName').innerHTML = filename;
        }
      }
```

Return will disallow file to put in your file upload control so this will solve your problem

Please check **[demo](http://jsbin.com/muxog/1/)** here

Comment: i have tried the same script you mentioned ,but it didnt work. check screenshot attached in question

Comment: Hello please add this line `document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value='';` i have put in my function check above function you forgot to add this line

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it this way using jquery:

```
    $(function () {        
    $('<%= fileUploadCV.ClientID %>').change(function () {

        //because this is single file upload I use only first index
        var f = this.files[0]

        //here I check if the file size is bigger than 8 MB (numbers below are in bytes)
        if (f.size > 8388608 || f.fileSize > 8388608)
        {
           //show an alert to the user
           alert("Allowed file size exceeded. (Max. 8 MB)")

           //and RESET file upload control
           this.value = null;
        }
    })
});
```